# Output within Do loop automatically suppressed?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
Do[n = i + 1;
 Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
 , {i, Range[0, 5, 1]}]
```

On my Mathematica version 9, the above code gets no plots made. It seems that all outputs from statements within a Do loop are automatically suppressed? It there anyway to "unsuppress" the output?

I do need the output to be shown WITHIN the loop, so easy solutions such as the following won't address my real need, although it is able to display the output eventually:

```
list = {};
Do[n = i + 1;
  temp = Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
  AppendTo[list, temp];
  , {i, Range[0, 5, 1]}];
list
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way any output can be shown within a Do loop, is if you -Print- it. This applies to plotting as well, so the following works and the -Print- wrapper around -Plot- is necessary:

```
Do[n = i + 1;
 Print[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]];
 , {i, Range[0, 5, 1]}]
```

But does anyone know why Do loop suppresses all outputs? I thought only semicolon ";" suppresses output?

BTW, Print[Plot[]] seems a pretty cumbersome solution. Displaying output within a loop should be often-used practice, right? And we have to resort to this?

Answer (score 0):

OP: *I do need the output to be shown WITHIN the loop*

An alternative to `Print` is to use `Dynamic`, e.g.

```
Clear[f]
Table[f[i] = Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {360, 214}], {i, 0, 5}];
Dynamic[Grid[Transpose[Partition[Table[f[i], {i, 0, 5}], 2]]]]
Do[n = i + 1;
 Pause[0.5];
 f[i] = Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {i, Range[0, 5, 1]}]
```